# Do my clients need to update their .Net Framework 4 (VS SP1)

Tags: windows-7, .net-4.0, windows-xp, visual-studio-2010

If i update my VS to SP1, will my clients need to update their computers with the latest 4.0 update? Or is it deployed with the dlls?

I dont plan on using the Platform Update
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/18/microsoft-net-framework-4-platform-update-1.aspx

But im thrown off because of this.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871

So if its the latter, would i still need to update my clients with this as well? Or are they handled in windows updates? Or are they released in dlls?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go with no on it for now until i do more testing... But after researching it looks like it can be a targeted build.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2011/04/21/net-framework-4-platform-update-1.aspx
and
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/18/microsoft-net-framework-4-platform-update-1.aspx

Both seem to point towards not having to update the client unless you are doing a PU1 build...

So im going with No...

Comment: Just finished some testing and as long as you use FW4 as your target build, it'll be okay and will work on the clients currennt FW... The Platform Update didn't get installed with the FW4 update, so disregard the links. those are both targeted downloads and targeted builds...